# Echo Inside of a PHP Include

Tags: php, arrays, include

I'm quite new to PHP. I have created an array which I have included however when I need to echo a url which is in my `settings` array it just gives me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'templateurl' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Comment: Here's my code. ` <?php include('echo "$settings['templateurl']" hi.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php include('hi.php'); echo $settings['templateurl'];?>
```

You need to include the file first and then you are able to retrieve the data from it.

Comment: Thanks. What would I do if I wanted to get two things from the array? `include('echo $settings['templateurl']echo $template['templateheader']');` Where templateheader is the path of a file.

Comment: Don't make the same mistake as above. Look at the code I have given you and read. Do the include first and then you can use the other variables inside. As per your example: 

<?php 
echo $settings['currenttemplateurl']; 
echo $template['templateheader'];
?>

If the header is the path just do <?php include($template['templateheader']); ?>

Comment: I have decided not to have the file names in the array. However, when I use this method. I seem to get around 5000 PHP errors. I think it is looking for the files in the same directory as the index.php is in. I'm so confused.

Comment: You need to specify where the file is located.  e.g. <?php include('path/to/file/of/header_template.php'); ?> and if it's just a variable  <?php include('path/to/file/of/'.$header_template.php); ?> I have added the quote only between the text and when it starts with $ it's without single quotes.

Comment: The file path is in the templateurl part. The file I need to include from that path is hi.php

Comment: Then it would be <?php include($header_template.'/hi.php'); ?>

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working :)